# Excel formatting question, default line color

Tags: excel, asp-classic

What is the default line setting in an Excel spreadsheet?  You know, the line that goes around the cell?

Color?
Line thickness?
Transparency?

I am creating a workbook using asp and html and want to format the lines so that it looks like the default settings.

Many thanks, R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color I show in Excel 2007 is HEX #D0D7E5 and it's 1 pixel in width

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.  One question, how did you find that out?

Comment: I opened Excel and used an app called ColorPic from www.iconico.com to grab the color of the gridlines. It also showed, on a zoomed level, the width of the line